# Select data from multiple tables with Kohana ORM v3

Tags: mysql, select, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I can't seem to select data from multiple tables with Kohana ORM.

When I do:

```
$obj = orm::factory('a')
         ->join('b')
         ->on('a.b_id','=','b.id')
         ->select ('b.*','a.*')
         ->find_all();
```

the only variables available in `$obj` are from table `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't overwrite table a variables with table b ones as you're instancing the Model_A, not Model_B ( ORM::factory('a') ).

When you do this, orm will automatically append select($this->_table_name.*) after all other selects so the previous ones (their keys) will be overwritten.